# Pygame AI drones

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, artificial-intelligence, collision

Hi i am working on a ice sumo type game and currently in works of a singleplayer mode. My plan is to have the player fend off against bots that spawn maybe every 5 seconds and their sole purpose is to hit the player, would be as simple as going towards the player's current (x,y). The score is based on how many bots the player has knocked out until he dies. The thing is I don't really know how to code it because my collision detection was based off a multiplayer mode where I compared player 1 and player 2's x and y's. Could anyone help me ? Thanks. This is what I have currently everything works right now and I am in works of the "singleplayer" function where I need to include the ai and stuff.

```
import pygame, sys, time
from pygame.locals import *
import random
import math


#Colors
colorRed=pygame.Color(241,59,62)
colorPurple=pygame.Color(200,254,249)
colorBlue=pygame.Color(52, 207, 235)
colorGreen=pygame.Color(100,182,100)
colorWhite=pygame.Color(255,250,250)
colorBlack=pygame.Color(0,0,0)
colorOrange=pygame.Color(242,164,0)
colorBrown=pygame.Color(148,103,58)
colorBlue2=pygame.Color(37, 45, 204)

#Dimensions
w=800
h=600
pygame.init()
fpsClock=pygame.time.Clock()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((w,h))
pygame.display.set_caption ('Ice Fighters')
centerX=w//2
centerY=h//2
point=3
pointx=240
gameEnd_p=1
gameEnd_px=340
option=False
x1_wins=0
x2_wins=0

# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ TEXT ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
bigFont = pygame.font.Font('shark_party.ttf',64)
smallFont = pygame.font.Font("shark_party.ttf",32)
tinyFont = pygame.font.Font('shark_party.ttf', 16)
titleText = bigFont.render("Ice Fighters", True, colorBlue)
multiplayerText=smallFont.render("Multiplayer", True, colorBlue2,)
singleplayerText=smallFont.render("Singleplayer", True, colorBlue2)
intructionsText=smallFont.render("How to Play", True, colorBlue2)
leaderboardText=smallFont.render("Leaderboard", True, colorBlue2)
game_endText=bigFont.render("GAME OVER", True, colorRed)
replayText=smallFont.render ("Play Again", True, colorBlue)
returnText=smallFont.render ("Main Menu", True, colorBlue)
menu_upText=tinyFont.render ("= Menu Up", True, colorBlack)
menu_downText=tinyFont.render ('= Menu Down',True, colorBlack)
menu_returnText=tinyFont.render ('= ENTER', True, colorBlack)

def game_end():
    while True:
        screen.fill(colorBlack)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            #Game Exit
            if event.type== QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type==KEYDOWN:
                if event.key==K_s:
                    global gameEnd_p
                    global gameEnd_px
                    if gameEnd_p==1:
                        gameEnd_px+=75
                        gameEnd_p-=1
                    elif gameEnd_p==0:
                        gameEnd_px-=75
                        gameEnd_p+=1 
                if event.key==K_w:
                    if gameEnd_p==1:
                        gameEnd_px+=75
                        gameEnd_p-=1
                    elif gameEnd_p==0:
                        gameEnd_px-=75
                        gameEnd_p+=1
                if event.key==K_RETURN:
                    if gameEnd_p==0:
                        title()
                    if gameEnd_p==1:
                        game()
        screen.blit(game_endText,(230,50))
        screen.blit(replayText,(300,325))
        screen.blit(returnText,(300,400))
        pygame.draw.circle(screen,colorRed,(280,gameEnd_px),10)
        pygame.display.update()
        fpsClock.tick(60)


def title():
    while True:
        screen.fill(colorBlack)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            #Game Exit
            if event.type== QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type==KEYDOWN:
                if event.key==K_s:
                    global point
                    global pointx
                    if point==3:
                        pointx+=75
                        point-=1
                    elif point==2:
                        pointx+=75
                        point-=1
                    elif point==1:
                        pointx+=75
                        point-=1
                    elif point==0:
                        pointx-=225
                        point+=3
                if event.key==K_w:
                    if point==3:
                        pointx+=225
                        point-=3
                    elif point==2:
                        pointx-=75
                        point+=1
                    elif point==1:
                        pointx-=75
                        point+=1
                    elif point==0:
                        pointx-=75
                        point+=1
                if event.key==K_RETURN:
                    if point==2:
                        option=True
                        game()
                    elif point==1:
                        option=True
                        instruct()


        #Background
        title_bg=pygame.image.load("icebiome3.png")
        screen.blit(title_bg,(0,0))
        screen.blit(titleText, (200,50))
        screen.blit(singleplayerText, (300,225))
        screen.blit(multiplayerText, (300,300))
        screen.blit(intructionsText, (300,375))
        screen.blit(leaderboardText, (300,450))
        screen.blit(menu_upText, (700,450))
        screen.blit(menu_downText, (700,475))
        screen.blit(menu_returnText, (700,500))
        pygame.draw.circle(screen,colorRed,(280,pointx),10)
        pygame.draw.circle(screen,colorWhite,(685,460),10)
        pygame.draw.circle(screen,colorRed,(685,485),10)
        pygame.draw.circle(screen,colorBlue2,(685,510),10)
        pygame.display.update()
        fpsClock.tick(60)

def instruct():
    while True:
        screen.fill(colorBlack)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            #Game Exit
            if event.type== QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type==KEYDOWN:
                if event.key==K_RETURN:
                    title()
        instruct_bg=pygame.image.load('instruct.png')
        instruct_sprite=pygame.image.load('instructsprite.png')

        screen.blit(instruct_bg,(0,0))
        screen.blit(returnText, (325,550))
        pygame.draw.circle(screen,colorRed,(310,568),10)
        pygame.display.update()
        fpsClock.tick(60)

def singleplayer():

    stageR=250
    def stage (centerX,centerY):
        """stage (centerX,centerY) - creates a stage with given centerpoint"""
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, colorBlue, (centerX,centerY),stageR)

    #Character 1
    xR=int((stageR//10))
    x1=centerX
    y1=centerY
    x1_dir=0
    y1_dir=0
    solo_wins=0
    def char1 (x1,y1):
        """char1 (x1,y1) - creates char1 at given coordinates"""
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, colorRed, (x1,y1),xR)

    while True:
        screen.fill(colorBlack)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            #Game Exit
            if event.type== QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

     # ~~~~~~~~~~ COLLISION DETECTION ~~~~~~~~~~~

        v12 = pygame.math.Vector2(x1-x2, y1-y2)
        distance = v12.length()
        hit_dist = 2*xR
        if distance <= hit_dist:
            # vector beteween center points
            nv = v12.normalize()
            # movement direction and combined relative movement
            d1 = pygame.math.Vector2(x1_dir, y1_dir)
            d2 = pygame.math.Vector2(x2_dir, y2_dir)
            dd = d1 - d2
            if dd.length() > 0:
                # normalized movement and normal distances
                ddn = dd.normalize()
                dir_dist  = ddn.dot(v12)
                norm_dist = pygame.math.Vector2(-ddn[0], ddn[1]).dot(v12)
                # minimum distance along the line of relative movement
                min_dist = math.sqrt(hit_dist*hit_dist - norm_dist*norm_dist)
                if dir_dist < min_dist:
                    # update postions of the players so that the distance is 2*xR
                    d1l, d2l = d1.length(), d2.length()
                    d1n = d1/d1l if d1l > 0 else d1
                    d2n = d2/d2l if d2l > 0 else d2
                    x1 -= d1n.x * d1l / (d1l+d2l)
                    y1 -= d1n.y * d1l / (d1l+d2l)
                    x2 -= d2n.x * d2l / (d1l+d2l)
                    y2 -= d2n.y * d2l / (d1l+d2l)
                    # recalculate vector beteween center points
                    v12 = pygame.math.Vector2(x1-x2, y1-y2)
                    nv = v12.normalize()

                # reflect movement vectors
                rd1 = d1.reflect(nv)
                rd2 = d2.reflect(nv)
                len1, len2 = rd1.length(), rd2.length()
                if len1 > 0:
                    rd1 = rd1 * len2 / len1
                    x1_dir, y1_dir = rd1.x, rd1.y
                else:
                    x1_dir, y1_dir = -x2_dir, -y2_dir
                if len2 > 0:
                    rd2 = rd2 * len1 / len2
                    x2_dir, y2_dir = rd2.x, rd2.y
                else:
                    x2_dir, y2_dir = -x1_dir, -y1_dir

         #MOVEMENT
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    # -------------------- CHAR1 MOVEMENT  WASD  --------------------
        if keys[K_d] or keys[K_a]:
            x1_dir += 0.1 if keys[K_d] else -0.1
        else:
            x1_dir *= 0.98

        if keys[K_w] or keys[K_s]:
            y1_dir += 0.1 if keys[K_s] else -0.1
        else:
            y1_dir *= 0.98

        stage (centerX,centerY)
        char1 (round(x1),round(y1))
        x1+=x1_dir
        y1+=y1_dir
        pygame.display.update()
        fpsClock.tick(60)

def game():

    #Stage
    stageR=250
    def stage (centerX,centerY):
        """stage (centerX,centerY) - creates a stage with given centerpoint"""
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, colorBlue, (centerX,centerY),stageR)

    #Character 1
    xR=int((stageR//10))
    x1=int(centerX-(stageR*0.8))
    y1=centerY
    x1_dir=0
    y1_dir=0
    global x1_wins
    x1_wins=0
    def char1 (x1,y1):
        """char1 (x1,y1) - creates char1 at given coordinates"""
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, colorRed, (x1,y1),xR)

    #Character 2
    x2=int(centerX+(stageR*0.8))
    y2=centerY
    x2_dir=0
    y2_dir=0
    global x2_wins
    x2_wins=0
    def char2 (x2,y2):
        """char2 (x2,y2) - creates char1 at given coordinates"""
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, colorGreen, (x2,y2),xR)


    def score ():
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, colorOrange, (50,30), (int(xR-5)))
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, colorBlack, (50,30), (int(xR-10)))
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, colorOrange, (100,30), (int(xR-5)))
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, colorBlack, (100,30), (int(xR-10)))
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, colorOrange, (150,30), (int(xR-5)))
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, colorBlack, (150,30), (int(xR-10)))

        pygame.draw.circle(screen, colorOrange, (750,30), (int(xR-5)))
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, colorBlack, (750,30), (int(xR-10)))
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, colorOrange, (700,30), (int(xR-5)))
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, colorBlack, (700,30), (int(xR-10)))
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, colorOrange, (650,30), (int(xR-5)))
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, colorBlack, (650,30), (int(xR-10)))

    def x1score ():
        if x1_wins>0:
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, colorOrange, (50,30), (int(xR-5)))
        if x1_wins>1:
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, colorOrange, (100,30), (int(xR-5)))
        if x1_wins>2:
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, colorOrange, (150,30), (int(xR-5)))

    def x2score ():
        if x2_wins>0:
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, colorOrange, (750,30), (int(xR-5)))
        if x2_wins>1:
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, colorOrange, (700,30), (int(xR-5)))
        if x2_wins>2:
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, colorOrange, (650,30), (int(xR-5)))

    while True:
        screen.fill(colorBlack)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            #Game Exit
            if event.type== QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

    # ~~~~~~~~~~ COLLISION DETECTION ~~~~~~~~~~~

        v12 = pygame.math.Vector2(x1-x2, y1-y2)
        distance = v12.length()
        hit_dist = 2*xR
        if distance <= hit_dist:
            # vector beteween center points
            nv = v12.normalize()
            # movement direction and combined relative movement
            d1 = pygame.math.Vector2(x1_dir, y1_dir)
            d2 = pygame.math.Vector2(x2_dir, y2_dir)
            dd = d1 - d2
            if dd.length() > 0:
                # normalized movement and normal distances
                ddn = dd.normalize()
                dir_dist  = ddn.dot(v12)
                norm_dist = pygame.math.Vector2(-ddn[0], ddn[1]).dot(v12)
                # minimum distance along the line of relative movement
                min_dist = math.sqrt(hit_dist*hit_dist - norm_dist*norm_dist)
                if dir_dist < min_dist:
                    # update postions of the players so that the distance is 2*xR
                    d1l, d2l = d1.length(), d2.length()
                    d1n = d1/d1l if d1l > 0 else d1
                    d2n = d2/d2l if d2l > 0 else d2
                    x1 -= d1n.x * d1l / (d1l+d2l)
                    y1 -= d1n.y * d1l / (d1l+d2l)
                    x2 -= d2n.x * d2l / (d1l+d2l)
                    y2 -= d2n.y * d2l / (d1l+d2l)
                    # recalculate vector beteween center points
                    v12 = pygame.math.Vector2(x1-x2, y1-y2)
                    nv = v12.normalize()

                # reflect movement vectors
                rd1 = d1.reflect(nv)
                rd2 = d2.reflect(nv)
                len1, len2 = rd1.length(), rd2.length()
                if len1 > 0:
                    rd1 = rd1 * len2 / len1
                    x1_dir, y1_dir = rd1.x, rd1.y
                else:
                    x1_dir, y1_dir = -x2_dir, -y2_dir
                if len2 > 0:
                    rd2 = rd2 * len1 / len2
                    x2_dir, y2_dir = rd2.x, rd2.y
                else:
                    x2_dir, y2_dir = -x1_dir, -y1_dir

    # ~~~~~~~~~~~ Borders ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

        x1_cdist=((centerX-x1)**2+(centerY-y1)**2)**0.5
        if x1_cdist>(stageR+30):
            time.sleep(3)
            x2=int(centerX+(stageR*0.8))
            y2=centerY
            x1=int(centerX-(stageR*0.8))
            y1=centerY
            x2_wins+=1
            x1_dir=0
            y1_dir=0
            print (x2_wins)
            if x2_wins>=3:
                game_end()


        x2_cdist=((centerX-x2)**2+(centerY-y2)**2)**0.5
        if x2_cdist>(stageR+30):
            time.sleep(3)
            x2=int(centerX+(stageR*0.8))
            y2=centerY
            x1=int(centerX-(stageR*0.8))
            y1=centerY
            x1_wins+=1
            x2_dir=0
            y2_dir=0
            print (x1_wins)
            if x1_wins>=3:
                game_end()



    #MOVEMENT
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    # -------------------- CHAR1 MOVEMENT  WASD  --------------------
        if keys[K_d] or keys[K_a]:
            x1_dir += 0.1 if keys[K_d] else -0.1
        else:
            x1_dir *= 0.98

        if keys[K_w] or keys[K_s]:
            y1_dir += 0.1 if keys[K_s] else -0.1
        else:
            y1_dir *= 0.98

    # -------------------- CHAR2 MOVEMENT  up/down/left/right --------------------
        if keys[K_RIGHT] or keys[K_LEFT]:
            x2_dir += 0.1 if keys[K_RIGHT] else -0.1
        else:
            x2_dir *= 0.98

        if keys[K_UP] or keys[K_DOWN]:
            y2_dir += 0.1 if keys[K_DOWN] else -0.1
        else:
            y2_dir *= 0.98

        score()
        stage (centerX,centerY)
        char1 (round(x1),round(y1))
        char2 (round(x2),round(y2))   
        x1score()
        x2score() 
        x1+=x1_dir
        y1+=y1_dir
        x2+=x2_dir
        y2+=y2_dir
        pygame.display.update()
        fpsClock.tick(60)

while True:
    singleplayer()
```

Comment: you should learn how to use class to group function for single object/player/bot and then you can easily keep many players or bots on list and use `for`-loop to check collisions with all elements/bots on list.

Comment: uh how would I do that? im not that experienced with this

Comment: it would need to change everything in code. Besides you don't respect [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) so it is hard to work with your code.

Comment: I tried to run your code and get `local variable 'x2' referenced before assignment` in singleplayer `v12 = pygame.math.Vector2(x1-x2, y1-y2)`

Comment: uh yea @furas singleplayer does not work at all right now

Comment: you should put code in functions so you could run them with different values - ie. `detect_collision(player1, player2)`, `detect_collision(player1, bots[0])`, `detect_collision(player1, bots[1])`. The same with border - `detect_border(player1)`, `detect_border(bots[0])`, `if detect_border(bots[1]) is True: game_end()`

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). This usually suggests that what you need is time with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.  Best of all, each tutorial will teach you a collection of related techniques, rather than merely solving the immediate problem.
You're attacking a problem that is quite far beyond your *current* programming skills -- and you've posed a question here that is too broad for Stack Overflow's stated purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I put some code in classes and functions and now it can display keep players and bots on list and use `for`-loop to use them.

There is too many changes to explain it.

`Player` and `Bot` have always the same code - `handle_events()` is different. `Player` check pressed keys, `Bot` generate random values which are treated as pressed keys.

```
import pygame, sys, time
from pygame.locals import *
import random
import math

# --- constants ---

#Colors
colorRed = pygame.Color(241,59,62)
colorPurple = pygame.Color(200,254,249)
colorBlue = pygame.Color(52, 207, 235)
colorGreen = pygame.Color(100,182,100)
colorWhite = pygame.Color(255,250,250)
colorBlack = pygame.Color(0,0,0)
colorOrange = pygame.Color(242,164,0)
colorBrown = pygame.Color(148,103,58)
colorBlue2 = pygame.Color(37, 45, 204)

#Dimensions
w = 800
h = 600

# --- classes ---

class Player():

    def __init__(self, x, y, R, color, k_left, k_right, k_up, k_down):

        self.x_start = x
        self.y_start = y
        self.R = R 
        self.color = color
        self.x_wins = 0

        self.k_left = k_left
        self.k_right = k_right
        self.k_up = k_up
        self.k_down = k_down

        self.reset()

    def reset(self):
        '''set values on restart'''       
        self.x = self.x_start
        self.y = self.y_start
        self.x_dir = 0
        self.y_dir = 0

    def draw(self, screen):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, self.color, (int(self.x), int(self.y)), self.R)

    def move(self):
        self.x += self.x_dir
        self.y += self.y_dir

    def handle_events(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[self.k_right] or keys[self.k_left]:
            self.x_dir += 0.1 if keys[self.k_right] else -0.1
        else:
            self.x_dir *= 0.98

        if keys[self.k_up] or keys[self.k_down]:
            self.y_dir += 0.1 if keys[self.k_down] else -0.1
        else:
            self.y_dir *= 0.98

class Bot():

    def __init__(self, x, y, R, color):

        self.x_start = x
        self.y_start = y
        self.R = R 
        self.color = color
        self.x_wins = 0

        self.reset()

    def reset(self):        
        self.x = self.x_start
        self.y = self.y_start
        self.x_dir = 0
        self.y_dir = 0

    def draw(self, screen):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, self.color, (int(self.x), int(self.y)), self.R)

    def move(self):
        self.x += self.x_dir
        self.y += self.y_dir

    def handle_events(self):
        dx = random.randint(-1, 1)
        if dx == 0:
            self.x_dir *= 0.98
        else:
            self.x_dir += 0.1 if dx > 0 else -0.1

        dy = random.randint(-1, 1)
        if dy == 0:
            self.y_dir *= 0.98
        else:
            self.y_dir += 0.1 if dy > 0 else -0.1

class Score():

    def __init__(self, x, y, step):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.step = step
        self.circles = 3
        self.wins = 0

    def draw(self, screen):
        r1 = int(xR-5)
        r2 = int(xR-10)

        x = self.x
        y = self.y
        for i in range(self.circles):
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, colorOrange, (x, y), r1)
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, colorBlack, (x, y), r2)
            x += self.step

        x = self.x
        y = self.y
        for i in range(self.wins):
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, colorOrange, (x, y), r1)
            x += self.step

# --- functions ---

def detect_collision(p1, p2):
    v12 = pygame.math.Vector2(p1.x-p2.x, p1.y-p2.y)
    distance = v12.length()
    hit_dist = 2*xR
    if distance <= hit_dist:
        # vector beteween center points
        nv = v12.normalize()
        # movement direction and combined relative movement
        d1 = pygame.math.Vector2(p1.x_dir, p1.y_dir)
        d2 = pygame.math.Vector2(p2.x_dir, p2.y_dir)
        dd = d1 - d2
        if dd.length() > 0:
            # normalized movement and normal distances
            ddn = dd.normalize()
            dir_dist  = ddn.dot(v12)
            norm_dist = pygame.math.Vector2(-ddn[0], ddn[1]).dot(v12)
            # minimum distance along the line of relative movement
            min_dist = math.sqrt(hit_dist*hit_dist - norm_dist*norm_dist)
            if dir_dist < min_dist:
                # update postions of the players so that the distance is 2*xR
                d1l, d2l = d1.length(), d2.length()
                d1n = d1/d1l if d1l > 0 else d1
                d2n = d2/d2l if d2l > 0 else d2
                p1.x -= d1n.x * d1l / (d1l+d2l)
                p1.y -= d1n.y * d1l / (d1l+d2l)
                p2.x -= d2n.x * d2l / (d1l+d2l)
                p2.y -= d2n.y * d2l / (d1l+d2l)
                # recalculate vector beteween center points
                v12 = pygame.math.Vector2(p1.x-p2.x, p1.y-p2.y)
                nv = v12.normalize()

            # reflect movement vectors
            rd1 = d1.reflect(nv)
            rd2 = d2.reflect(nv)
            len1, len2 = rd1.length(), rd2.length()
            if len1 > 0:
                rd1 = rd1 * len2 / len1
                p1.x_dir, p1.y_dir = rd1.x, rd1.y
            else:
                p1.x_dir, p1.y_dir = -p2.x_dir, -p2.y_dir
            if len2 > 0:
                rd2 = rd2 * len1 / len2
                p2.x_dir, p2.y_dir = rd2.x, rd2.y
            else:
                p2.x_dir, p2.y_dir = -p1.x_dir, -p1.y_dir

def detect_border(player):
    distance = ((centerX-player.x)**2 + (centerY-player.y)**2)**0.5
    return distance > (stageR+30)

def game():
    players = []
    scores = []

    p1 = Player(int(centerX-(stageR*0.8)), centerY, int(stageR//10), colorRed, K_a, K_d, K_w, K_s)
    players.append(p1)
    #p2 = Player(int(centerX+(stageR*0.8)), centerY, int(stageR//10), colorGreen, K_LEFT, K_RIGHT, K_UP, K_DOWN) 
    #players.append(p2)

    b = Bot(int(centerX+(stageR*0.8)), centerY, int(stageR//10), colorGreen) 
    players.append(b)
    b = Bot(centerX, int(centerY+(stageR*0.8)), int(stageR//10), colorOrange) 
    players.append(b)
    b = Bot(centerX, int(centerY-(stageR*0.8)), int(stageR//10), colorWhite) 
    players.append(b)
    b = Bot(centerX, centerY, int(stageR//10), colorBrown) 
    players.append(b)

    s1 = Score(50, 30, 50)
    s2 = Score(750, 30, -50)
    scores.append(s1)
    scores.append(s2)

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            #Game Exit
            if event.type== QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        # ~~~ COLLISION DETECTION ~~~

        for p1 in players:
            for p2 in players:
                if p1 != p2:
                    detect_collision(p1, p2)

        # ~~~ Borders ~~~

        for i, p in enumerate(players):
            if detect_border(p):
                time.sleep(3)

                for x in players:
                    x.reset()

                if i == 0:
                    scores[1].wins += 1
                else:
                    scores[0].wins += 1

                print(scores[0].wins, scores[1].wins)

        for s in scores:                    
            if s.wins >= 3:
                #game_end()
                return

        # ~~~ MOVEMENT ~~~

        for p in players:
            p.handle_events()

        for p in players:
            p.move()

        # --- draws --- (without events and moves)
        screen.fill(colorBlack)
        # stage
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, colorBlue, (centerX,centerY), stageR)
        # players
        for p in players:
            p.draw(screen)
        # scores
        for s in scores:
            s.draw(screen)
        # update
        pygame.display.update()
        fpsClock.tick(60)

# --- main ---

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w,h))
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
centerX = screen_rect.centerx
centerY = screen_rect.centery
pygame.display.set_caption('Ice Fighters')
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()

stageR = 250
xR = int((stageR//10))

game()
```